# How to display items (paths of images) in ListView from ArrayList using ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-listview, path

How can I display items (paths of images) in ListView from ArrayList using ArrayAdapter? My code doesn't work - it does not print the list of paths of images.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    ArrayList<String> urllist = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView list;

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urllist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery();

            }
        });
    }
    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            String name = data.getData().getPath();
            urllist.add(name); //here I add each path to list
            //tv.setText(TextUtils.concat(tv.getText(), " ", name));
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to call the notifyDataSetChanged method

Answer (score 0):

While you're updating your `urllist`, you also need to notify the adapter. To do this, make your `adapter` a field instead.

Then when you're adding items to `urllist`, don't forget to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
ArrayList<String> urllist = new ArrayList<>();

// Make adapter a field
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // ...

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urllist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        // ...

        urllist.add(name); //here I add each path to list
        // Notify the adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

        String name = data.getData().getPath();
        urllist.add(name); //here I add each path to list
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // assign urllist to adapter      
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urllist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```